# Gives grades according to marks

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

i have SSRS report i want to give "Accepted" if value between 50 and 65 and gives "Good" if value between 65 and 75 and gives "V good" if value between 75 and 85 and gives "Excellent" if value between 85 and 100
how can i do it my code :

```
=(IIF(Fields!marks.Value >50, "fail", 0)) And (IIF(Fields!marks.Value <65, "Accepted", 0))
```

Comment: You have to decide what "between" means. Is 65 "accepted" or "good"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Switch` function to accomplish this:

```
=Switch(
  Fields!marks.Value < 50, "fail",
  Fields!marks.Value < 65, "accepted",
  Fields!marks.Value < 75, "good",
  Fields!marks.Value < 85, "v good",
  True, "excellent"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a switch statement:

```
=switch(
      Fields!marks.Value<50,"Fail",
      Fields!marks.Value>= 50 and Fields!marks.Value<65,"Accepted",
      Fields!marks.Value>= 65 and Fields!marks.Value<75,"Good",
      Fields!marks.Value>= 75 and Fields!marks.Value<85,"V Good",
      Fields!marks.Value>= 85 and Fields!marks.Value<100,"Excellent",
,"")
```